# Using source to make a wireframe plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have an R script that builds a data frame `DF` and then calls every script in a directory `Rscripts` using `source` to generate plots. So a typical execution looks like

```
pdf('output.pdf')
source('Rscripts/make_plot.r')
dev.off()
```

where `Rscripts/make_plot.r` might contain something like

```
plot(DF$x, DF$y)
```

So far this strategy has worked beautifully (although I don't know if it's the recommended way to do things). However, I'm hitting a wall now. One of my Rscripts makes plots using `wireframe` instead of `plot`, and so for some reason calling `source` on that file doesn't produce a plot. A small example reproducing the issue can be found by putting the following in `make_plot.r`:

```
library("lattice")
N <- 10
s <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
wireframe(z~x*y, data=data.frame(x=rep(s, each=N), y=rep(s, N), z=rep(s, N)))
```

which works when called on its own but generates no plot when called via `source`.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)

> **Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?**
>
> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the graph. Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but do not display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis graphics in S-PLUS). The print() method for the graph object produces the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the command line, the result is automatically printed, but in source() or inside your own functions you will need an explicit print() statement.

Since `wireframe()` is a Lattice function, you will need to wrap it in a `print()`